# How do I specify NLog's config by environment using core dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, nlog

I'm using .net core with NLog, and am trying to achieve different setting based on environment
Using the static initialization I got it work by using:

```cs
private static NLog.Logger log =
    NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(Startup.NLogConfig).GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

where `Startup.NLogConfig` is initialized on the Startup class like so:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    NLogConfig = "nlog.file.config";
else
    NLogConfig = "nlog.blob.config";
```

But I don't know how to specify it for the Dependency Injection:

```cs
public SomeController(ILogger<SomeController> log)
{
   // log needs to be initialized using the right config based on the environment context
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used dependency injection, but when reading the manual then you use interfaces and then register a concrete implementation of the interface.

This is the concrete implementation:

```
NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(Startup.NLogConfig).GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Since you are talking about NetCore and dependency injection (without specifying any specific dependency-injection-container) then I guess you should use Microsoft Dependency Injection and Microsoft Extension Logging (MEL).

See this example for how to setup NLog as LoggingProvider-implementation, and then using MEL-ILogger-interfaces:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs

Notice how the implementation is configured at startup (along with setting up the dependency-injection-container), and then all business-logic-classes acquires ILogger-interfaces to perform their logging (to whatever implementation registered in the dependency-injection-container).

Comment: From what I understand, in this example the implementation is configured at startup  to catch errors, but I don't see how to setup the Nlog config file in the subsequent instantiations by the dependency injection logic

Comment: @AbirStolov The magic happens in the call to `UseNLog` is connects the NLog.config loaded at startup in `NLog.Web.NLogBuilder` with the ILogger-interface.

Comment: Okay, So how can I specify the settings file in the `UseNLog` Method?

Comment: @AbirStolov Right now the recommended way is to setup NLog-config before setting up dependency-injection. See also the link in my answer. But soon NLog.Web.AspNetCore ver. 4.9 will be released. Then you can use `ILoggingBuilder.AddNLog("nlog.config")`.