# Stop NLog from logging when I'm debugging the app on my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, .net-6.0, nlog

I have a .Net 6 Web API which is using NLog (version 5.0.2). Currently, when an unhandled exception occurs, it is being logged, regardless of the machine the Web API is running on. I'd like it to only log these unhandled exceptions when the API is hosted on our hosting server (in our case, Azure App Service) and not when I am debugging the API locally on my machine.

I've Googled this but have found nothing. I thought there could perhaps be some filter based on a layout such as "{machinename}", so i could say if {machinename} = 'mypc', then don't log. But as far as I can see, there's no such thing.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is not that the LogEvent occurs, but that it is sent to a special target, that should not be used when debugging locally.

Instead of having multiple environment specific NLog.config-files, then you could also do this at startup:

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
#if DEBUG
        // First thing
        NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("DebugLogLevel", "Off");
        NLog.LogManager.ReconfigureExistingLoggers();
#endif

        // Everything else as usual
    }
}
```

The NLog.config can then skip logging to your special target when debugging:

```
<nlog>
    <variable key="DefaultLogLevel" value="${gdc:DebugLogLevel:whenEmpty=Info}" />

    <rules>
         <logger name="*" minLevel="${DefaultLogLevel}" writeTo="SpecialTarget" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration

Comment: Thank you ThomasArdal. I struggled to make it work at first, but then I followed the link you provided, and by following that example, it worked.

Comment: For the "#if DEBUG" statement, i had to add an "#else" statement, to set "DebugLogLevel" to "Info", because the ":whenEmpty=Info" bit in nlog.config didn't seem to work. But maybe I just did something wrong...

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez Was a little too hasty with the answer. I have now updated the NLog.config XML so it should be correct now. Always a good idea use `throwConfigExceptions="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a previous question that may provide some relevant information:
[How do I specify NLog's config by environment using core dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076030/how-do-i-specify-nlogs-config-by-environment-using-core-dependency-injection)

You will likely need to implement some sort of system to identify the environment to your application, most likely an environmental variable. From there you have several options for handling this for example you could configure your logging framework to only log to certain outputs in production vs development or you could implement exception handling middleware to handle exceptions differently for different environments.

Luckily ASP.NET 6 handles this fairly well out of the box and it is not unusual behavior so most of the tools are well documented to do this, most likely you'll be setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environmental variable on your local machine vs the deployed production machine and then using that value to change the behavior of your application

I recommend checking out these resources:

- [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Configuration in ASP.NET Core - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Using Environment specific NLog Config](https://edi.wang/post/2019/4/3/use-environment-specific-nlogconfig-in-aspnet-core)

Comment: Thank you jhambright. The last link you sent me ("Using Environment specific NLog.config") is pretty much what I was looking for. Only thing I need to figure out is how to make that example work, as they use NLog.ConfigureNLog to build the logger instance in their Program.cs, whereas I'm using NLog.LogManager (because I'm registering a layout renderer). But I think I will make it work. Thank you! Very nicely written answer, I really appreciate it.